# Why do these mathematical texts not include the potential term in the "Schrödinger equation"

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Here are two excerpts

> Schrödinger's equation $$iu_t+\Delta u=0$$
>   Lawrence C. Evans, *Partial Differential Equations* (2010)

and

> Physically, the initial-value problem for the linear Schrödinger equation
>   $$u_t=i\Delta u+\phi,\qquad t\in\Bbb R,\quad x\in\Bbb R^3,\quad i=\sqrt{-1},\quad u(0,x)=f(x)$$
>   [...]
>
> Weihrauch and Zhong, *Computing Schrödinger propagators on Type-2 Turing machines* (2006)

Notably, neither of these two forms have the potential term, unless I'm missing something. Is it standard to talk about the "Schrödinger equation" as not having a potential term?  In the second image, there is a so-called "forcing term", which I've never seen in physical settings, but there isn't a potential term, which is almost always present in physically relevant problems. What's going on there?

Comment: The author probably should have said "Free" Schr\"odinger

Comment: Without knowing the context, I'd guess the author probably just wants to talk about the $V = 0$ form of the equation, without trying to model a phsyical potential.